# PMD Apex ExcessiveClassLength & ExcessivePublicCount Rule error

Tags: apex, security, pmd

Getting the following error message when I Ran the PMD scripts for Apex Class.

`ExcessiveClassLength -- Avoid really long classes.` 
`ExcessivePublicCount -- This class has a bunch of public methods and attributes`

Both PMD Errors Occurs in Wrapper Class.

**ExcessiveClassLength  Code Below:**

```
    public Class StudentProgramTypeWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        public Id programRecordTypeId {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public string programTypeName {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public string programTypekey {get;set;}
    }
```

**ExcessivePublicCount Code Below:**

```
    public Class ParentProgramWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        public Id parentProgramId {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String parentProgramName {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String parentProgramDesc {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public string qualifiedName {get;set;} 
        @AuraEnabled
        public boolean showdatatable {get;set;}  
        @AuraEnabled
        public boolean isstudntProgramAssigned {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public string minNumberOfProgramDesc {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public string maxNumberOfProgramDesc {get;set;} 
        @AuraEnabled
        public decimal minNumberOfProgram {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public decimal maxNumberOfProgram {get;set;} 
        @AuraEnabled
        public decimal numberOfProgramSeleted {get;set;} 
    }
```

Can anyone please guide me to solve this error.

Comment: Are these declared as inner class in another outer class?

Comment: Yes, Wrapper Class used inner class in another outer class

Comment: That's probably the root cause. The outer class (which has these wrapper classes) might be quite long and might have any public methods/ attributes. Break down the outer class into smaller functional units and declare these as separate class by themselves.  For the PMD rule details, refer to https://pmd.github.io/pmd/pmd_rules_apex_design.html#excessivepubliccount & https://pmd.github.io/pmd/pmd_rules_apex_design.html#excessiveclasslength

Comment: Do you mean Each Wrapper Class needs to Create a New Outer Class?

Comment: Yes, if the outer class still long after refactoring.